# Does pgBouncer support different auth mechanisms for client and server?

Tags: pgbouncer

Is it possible to have trust based authentication from client to pgbouncer (1.17.0) and certificate authentication from pgbouncer to postgres (14) server in a system?

Comment: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#authentication-settings this might be helpful.

Comment: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#server_tls_sslmode this is the config for enabling TLS connection to PostgresSQL in the pgbouncer

Comment: Issue here is I am trying trust based auth on client side and SSL based on server side, but once a client is authenticated using trust based, the ssl mode at server (server_tls_* setting) is not being taken into consideration. I want to keep the client cert at pgbouncer and when the connection come from clients, use ssl between pgbouncer and database to authenticate.